# Adding custom Siri command to shortcut

Tags: swift, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I have created a custom Siri command "Create route", I have created a custom intent file and everything is working fine. But there is a button to add the shortcut to the shortcuts. I need to do the same with out that button.

```
let addShortcutButton = INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton(style: .blackOutline)
        let intent = GoodMapsIntent()
        intent.suggestedInvocationPhrase = "Create route"
        addShortcutButton.shortcut = INShortcut(intent: intent)
        addShortcutButton.delegate = self

        let interaction = INInteraction(intent: intent, response: nil)
        interaction.donate( completion: {_ in
            print("completed")
        })
        
        addShortcutButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(addShortcutButton)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            addShortcutButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            addShortcutButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
        ])
```

This is my code to add the phrase to shortcuts. By clicking add to Siri button it will show a view controller named INUIViewController. The following is the code for that.

```
extension ViewController : INUIAddVoiceShortcutButtonDelegate {
    func present(_ addVoiceShortcutViewController: INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController, for addVoiceShortcutButton: INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton) {
        addVoiceShortcutViewController.delegate = self
        present(addVoiceShortcutViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func present(_ editVoiceShortcutViewController: INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewController, for addVoiceShortcutButton: INUIAddVoiceShortcutButton) {
        editVoiceShortcutViewController.delegate = self
        present(editVoiceShortcutViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension ViewController : INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewControllerDelegate {

    func addVoiceShortcutViewController(_ controller: INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController,
                                        didFinishWith voiceShortcut: INVoiceShortcut?,
                                        error: Error?) {
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            print("Error adding voice shortuct: %@", error)
        }

        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func addVoiceShortcutViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension ViewController : INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewControllerDelegate {

    func editVoiceShortcutViewController(_ controller: INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewController,
                                         didUpdate voiceShortcut: INVoiceShortcut?,
                                         error: Error?) {
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            print("Error adding voice shortcut: %@", error)
        }

        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func editVoiceShortcutViewController(_ controller: INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewController,
                                         didDeleteVoiceShortcutWithIdentifier deletedVoiceShortcutIdentifier: UUID) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func editVoiceShortcutViewControllerDidCancel(_ controller: INUIEditVoiceShortcutViewController) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[This is my Intent definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPf9y.png)

[These are the parameters that I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmpCk.png)

Everything is working fine but I need to add the shortcut "create route" to shortcuts and need to do the action without this screen or confirming any of these protocols.